# Calling PHP tags from within a groovy gsp using grails php plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, grails, plugins

I am trying to integrate a wordpress blog into my grails application. Wordpress is php, so grails obviously doesn't immediately work with that. There is a (quite dated) grails php plugin here: http://grails.org/plugin/php, which I've downloaded and installed. The plugin worked great and allowed me to get Wordpress up and running.

The problem I'm having is trying to display the wordpress content within a groovy gsp page. The content is accessible using PHP tags. However, the description of the grails php plugin states:

- You could use JSP include to load PHP page from a JSP page under
  web-app
- You cannot include a .php from a .gsp yet, check [GRAILS-3906](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3906)

So I can't include php in a gsp. They mention some workarounds like including entire php pages, but... am I out of luck?

Has anyone done this before? The web seems so sparse for answers. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the Franki Sans approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather try the opposite approach:
Let the site be developed using wordpress and a wp-plugin can integrate your grails app using restful call proxyed by e custom wordpress plugin.